# Abstract callback in reflection method of java

Tags: java, reflection, abstract

I have a class in jar of which I want to invoke a method. But that method has parameter of abstract class and that abstract class is inner method of class in jar. AbstractClassA is a HIDDEN class. Here is code:

```
   public class A{

        private invokeThisMethod(AbstractClassA object){
        }

        public abstract class AbstractClassA {
              public void update(int remaining){}
        }
   }



public class myClass{

     //using Reflection get object of class A
      objectOfClassAusingReflection.inovke("invokeThisMethod", params)
}
```

Problem here is how do I create concrete implementation of AbstractClassA to pass in invoke method and get update method callbacks ?

Comment: if this concerns the API of a library, you might have to look in to the library's documentation, to find existing sub classes of the inner `AbstractClassA`. Usually you will find either (1) a specific implementation, you can instantiate via its constructor, or (2) a factory class, that offers you the generation of such an instance. Worst case, (3) you will have to implement it yourself as suggested in KDM's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
 AbstractClassA a = new AbstractClassA() {
      public void update(int remaining) {... do something...}
 };

 objectOfClassAusingReflection.inovke("invokeThisMethod", a);
```

Comment: No. Creating object of abstract class is not possible.

Comment: this is anonymous class of AbstractClassA .

Comment: @user531069 beware the curly braces behind the constructor. This implies an anonymous sub class. `new AbstractClassA() { /* specific implementation */ }`.

Comment: How do I even access it:
Class<?> callBack = Class.forName("com.package.A$AbstractClassA");
callBack callBackClassObject = new callBack () {
    public void update(int remaining) { ..something .. }
}

Error: callBack can not be resolved and asks me to create class

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of abstract class or any interface at runtime.
Instead create an anonymous class for this.

```
public abstract class A {
    public void fun(){....}
    public abstract void absFun();
}

public class MyClass {
    objectOfClassA = new A(){
        public void absFun(){...}
    }
}
```

Or you can first create implementation for that abstract classes for which you will have to create another class extending A

```
class AWrapper extends A {
    public class ImplementationClassA extends AbstractClassA {
        // override abstract functions...
    }
}
```

Now you can use this `Awrapper` class

```
AWrapper wrapperObj = new AWrapper();
A obj = wrapperObj; // just to make it clear that A can hold wrapperObj as it is implementation of it.
A.AbstractClassA absObj = wrapperObj.new ImplementationClassA();
...
objectOfClassAusingReflection.inovke("invokeThisMethod", params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work--

Here, i used `anonymus classes` for both outer and inner class and then with the help of `getdeclatedMethod` called your update method.

"TestAbs" is your jar class--

```
public abstract class TestAbs {

  private void invokeThisMethod(AbstractClassA object) {
  }

  public abstract class AbstractClassA {
    public void update(int remaining) {
    }
  }

}
```

Then calling your jar class from "TestAbs1" like below--

```
public class TestAbs1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestAbs.AbstractClassA abs = new TestAbs() {

      AbstractClassA a = new AbstractClassA() {
        public void update(int remaining) {
          System.out.println("Inside update method : " + remaining);

        }
      };
    }.a;

    try {
      int i = 1;

      Class<?> class1 = Class.forName("app.test.mytest.TestAbs$AbstractClassA"); -- (*Getting instance of inner class*)


      System.out.println(class1.getDeclaredMethod("update", int.class));
      class1.getDeclaredMethod("update", int.class).invoke(abs, i);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

The output i got is --

```
public void app.test.mytest.TestAbs$AbstractClassA.update(int)
Inside update method : 1
```

Answer to your Comment:-

What I understood from your comment is that, you wanted to call method from abstractClass which is hidden in outerclass.

As per my understanding, there is one way like below--

```
public abstract class TestAbs {

      private void invokeThisMethod(AbstractClassA object) {
      }

      private abstract class AbstractClassA {  --- your hidden class
        public void update(int remaining) {
        }
      }

    public class ImplementedClass extends AbstractClassA{ -- use implemented class here
      ....
      ...
     }

    }
```

And after that, use your ImplementedClass the same way mentioned above.
You can find reference example for private inner class [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) from java docs.

**Note**: In your question context, since your inner class and outer class is in jar, so I think it is difficult for you add implementation class in your jar.

In case, you find any alternatives, please let all knows about this;

thanks.

Comment: This looks really good but does not solve my problem completely. Is there any way that rather than invoking the update method, I listen to it whenever some other class calls it? Like I get's callbacks whenever update is triggered.

Comment: What is AbstractClassA is a hidden class which means I can not access it directly the way you did. How do I use it using reflection?